# How to get updated value of java variables?

Tags: java, variables, object, reference

I am trying to get updated value of a variable from other class. The variable's value is updating but only for it's own class. While another class which is trying to access the values through reference, is still getting the old value. Suppose there is a `private boolean` variable in `class1` which keeps on updating.
While `class2` accesses the the `boolean` variable of `class1` by `getter method`, something like this:

```
CLASS 1 CODE:

class A {
    private boolean state;
    boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Here the value of variable `state` keeps on updating by an `ActionEvent`

```
CLASS 2 CODE:

class B {
    void go() {
        A a = new A();
        while(true) {
            if(a.getState()) {
                //CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am always getting the original value of `state` variable in `class B` although the value is updating in `class A`. So, how can I get the updated value of a variable, from another class reference?

> EDIT:
>   It's kinda strange but the variables updates when the method is somehow called or *refreshed*. Like this:

```
CLASS 2 CODE:

class B {
    void go() {
        A a = new A();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(a.getState());
            if(a.getState()) {
                //CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just after the addition of `System.out.println(a.getState());`, we are getting the updated value. Please explain!

Answer (score 2):

You create a new instance of A on every loop iteration.
Just move A a = new A(); one line up:

```
class B {
    void go() {
        A a = new A();
        while(true) {
            if(a.getState()) {
                //CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, next, if you are using exactly this code, so you should set default state value to true. Because this code never reach //CODE.  private boolean state = true;

Comment: Please see, I've made an edit in the question. Coming to your part, I don't want the //CODE  to be triggered unless `state` becomes `true` by an `ActionEvent`

Comment: I can't understand how you can change state of your local variable "a" from outside if this is all code of "B". Are you really sure that system.out handle changes? Anyway looks like @Blackoutburst' answer fits better in you case

Comment: There is only one explanation that I can see - compiler optimized your code like me at comment above, that you use local object and check it's state without modification. So every time you use a side effect here (print or assign) compiler cannot optimize it and fairly check state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your bollean in any class you juste need to make it static

```
CLASS 1 CODE:

class A {
    private boolean state;
       public static boolean getState() {
            return state;
    }
}
```

and in the second class

```
CLASS 2 CODE:

class B {
    void go() {
        while(true) {
            if(A.getState == //true or false//) {
                //CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```